# Ionic - how to change permissions requestor name

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, ionic-framework, permissions

I have an Angular Ionic app that uses geolocation / Google Maps. When it requests permissions for location, on web and Android it uses the url (so localhost:4200, for example) and on iOS it just reads as "://".

Where do I configure the requestor name for permissions? I want it to read

> "App Name" Would Like To Use Your Current Location

So for clarity: I don't want the url on Android/Web, and I don't want the blank string on iOS. I want it to read as the app name.

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: inside `info.plist` file. open your application in xcode and go to App/App folder you will get info.plist file.

Comment: I have a partial answer: we were requesting permissions directly on app initialization. If you do that with no delay, then it uses both the native request pop-up (which has the app name) AND the HTML pop-up (which add the garbage :// name in there).

This still isn't solved for web and Android yet however, which still default to the URL requesting instead of the app name.